# Win 10, MS Publisher 365, page display is not same as in Publisher 2007

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-publisher

We created complex pages in Publisher 2007 running on win 10. Have updated to win 10, publisher 2010. Now text that filled the textbox (we write to the page) no longer fills the page/text box. There is a large white area at the bottom.

None of the pages are displayed accurately using .pub 2007 as the correct file.

We have 100's of .pub pages. Fixing them one at a time is not workable.

How do we get .pub 2007 files to display properly in .pub 2010, also .pub 2016, 2019, 2021(365)?

Are there settings that will make this happen? Is there a fix from MS support? Has someone written a patch?

A

Comment: I am confused.  Publisher for Office 365 is Publisher 365 - I have it here with Office.  Publisher 2010 is quite old. Do you have the correct version of Publisher?

Comment: Publisher 2007 and 2010 are both out of support and no patches for them are (or will be) available. If the document does not work properly in Publisher 365, then you will probably need to begin a process of new documents in Pub 365.  Possibly (only just possibly) print and convert back with Abbey OCR software.